# Rerender Tooltip when Scrolling React

Tags: css, reactjs, list, scroll, tooltip

Thanks for your help in advance, I have an issue with a tooltip, it is supposed that I should show the tooltip when a condition is given, but due to the scroll when rerendering the list the validation fails.
Here is working right, the complete list shows the tooltips where it is supposed to be. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UO6Yy.png)

But then, when I scroll down the view is re-render and the tooltip fails. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RCIlE.png)

The idea is that the tooltip (and the underline) should be shown when I have group names too long using this boolean `disableHoverListener={textDoesOverflow}`, and it is working at the beginning but then ... fails.

Here's the code and the styles.
Please help!!

```
    export const BaseFilteredUsersGroups: React.FC<IFilteredUsersGroups> = (props) => {
  const {
    userId,
    filteredGroupIds = [],
    localize,
  } = props;

  const sizeGroupsRef = React.useRef(null);
  const sizeTitleRef = React.useRef(null);

  const styles = useStyles();

  const usersGroups = useSelector((state: IDuxStore) => {
    const groups = filteredGroupIds.map(groupId => select.group.getGroupByGroupId(state, groupId));
    return groups.filter(group => group?.memberships?.some(user => user.userId === userId));
  });

  const labelTitle = localize.formatItems(usersGroups.map(group => group.title));

  const textDoesOverflow = sizeGroupsRef?.current?.getBoundingClientRect()?.width >= sizeTitleRef?.current?.getBoundingClientRect()?.width;

  const finalStyle = textDoesOverflow ? styles.groupTitle : styles.groupTitleOverflow;

  return (<div className={styles.usersGroups} ref={sizeGroupsRef}>
    {<Tooltip title={labelTitle} disableHoverListener={textDoesOverflow} placement="top" onScrollCapture={}>
      {<span className={finalStyle} ref={sizeTitleRef}>
        {labelTitle}
      </span>}
    </Tooltip>}
  </div >);
};
```

Here the styles:

```
export const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => {
  return createStyles({
    usersGroups:{
      textOverflow: 'ellipsis',
      overflow: 'hidden',
    },
    groupTitle: {
      whiteSpace: 'nowrap',
      fontWeight: theme.typography.fontWeightMedium,
      color: theme.palette.text.secondary,
    },
    groupTitleOverflow: {
      whiteSpace: 'nowrap',
      fontWeight: theme.typography.fontWeightMedium,
      color: theme.palette.text.secondary,
      textDecorationLine: 'underline',
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
          const textDoesOverflow = 
                    sizeGroupsRef?.current?.getBoundingClientRect()?.width 
                    >= sizeTitleRef?.current?.getBoundingClientRect()?.width;

          const finalStyle = textDoesOverflow ? styles.groupTitle : styles.groupTitleOverflow;
```

The conditional logic here is reversed. Right now if the text width is greater than the sizeTitleRef width it will return groupTitle not groupTitleOverflow. So instead you may want to switch up the ternary operator to this:

```
const finalStyle = textDoesOverflow ? styles.groupTitleOverflow : styles.groupTitle;
```